# How do I compare many string arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I have many arrays of strings such as:

```
private String[] ar1= {"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Books"};
private String[] ar2= {"Books", "Pepperoni", "Greatness"};
private String[] ar3= {"Whatever", "Whenever", "Pepperoni"};
```

How do I compare all these three arrays and get the results that a word "Pepperoni" is common between ar1, ar2 and ar3 or for example "Books" is common between only ar2 and ar1? I am able to compare two string arrays using for loops but how do do this for many such arrays?

Comment: what form of output you are expecting?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg I would like the output to be the word that is common along with the arrays in which it is common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a set

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ar1));
words.retainAll(Arrays.asList(ar2));
words.retainAll(Arrays.asList(ar3));
```

This takes the intersection of each of the arrays.

A more advanced option is to look at words which appear a number of times in many arrays.

```
Map<String, Long> words = Stream.of(ar1, ar2, ar3, ar4, ar5)
                               .flatMap(Stream::of)
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w,
                                                              Collectors.counting()));
```

This gives you a Map of each word and how many times it appears. You can add more arrays as required.

Comment: That's simple and effective, thanks!! But is there a way to automate this in a way where I may have tens of such arrays?

Comment: Good answer to first question *"a word "Pepperoni" is common between ar1, ar2 and ar3"*, but doesn't help with the second question *""Books" is common between only ar2 and ar1"*. For that, you'd need a `Map<String, Set<Integer>>`, to show which array (the `Integer`) each word is in. Any map entry with a value (`Set`) that has size equal to number of arrays, is an answer to first question too.

Comment: @Ravichandra yes, you can loop over all the arrays

Comment: Your stream version assumes that a word cannot occur multiple times in an array. Nothing in the question indicates whether that might be true, so you should specify such an assumption in the answer.

Comment: @Andreas it assume the arrays are Sets but you could wrap them to ensure this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary where the keys are the words. Now, you iterate over all words and add to the dictionary:

if the word is not in dict:

```
  dict[word] = 1;
```

else:

```
  dict[word]++;
```

At the end you iterate over the dictionary and all the keys that have value of 3 are the common between the tree arrays, this idea you could use for k arrays.
Also remember that first you have to eliminate the common words in the same array.

Comment: First, that is not Java. Second, there is no listed guarantee in the question text that says that a word cannot occur more than once in an array, so your solution wouldn't work if that were the case.